# How to force Identity Server 4 to route from /connect/authorize to my custom methods on each request?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, single-page-application

When a user (SPA based, no MVC) tries to log in to my application (auth code flow), they go to the endpoint specified in the well known document.

> https://localhost:5010/connect/authorize
> ?client_id=cool_client
> &response_type=code
> &redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/auth&scope=openid&param=1337

It works well and the IDS4 routes over the call to the controller below with the correct value of `returnUrl`. I do some magic and logic in there and sign in them to the application. They are redirected to the SPA and provided with a code to be exchanged for a token. Everything works just as supposed to and a correct, working token is issued..

```
[HttpGet("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn([FromQuery] string returnUrl)
{
  ...
  await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user);
  return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

When the user is signed in and attempts to authorize again, now with the access token (which they obtained using the code issued previously), they navigate to the very same endpoint with the very same query string. However, this time, the IDS4 handles the call differently. Instead of routing the call again to the method above, it automagically bounces the call to the URL from `returnUrl` without hitting the breaky in it.

I assumed it had to do with some optimization due to the presence of a valid access token (since the very same request after the token's expired routes me to my method again). However, I'd like to get the routing now because I need to do something with each incoming call, due to changed business requirement.

I googled the issue but found nothing (most of the material regards MVC nto SPA, anyway). I read the official docs and tried to scrutinize the quick-start application. After three days, I'm concluding that I can't find any useful info on the subject.

How can I force the routing to my custom method for each incoming request, including the ones that contain a valid access token?

Comment: When you already have a valid access token you don't have to authorize again, so it's by design. It's not very clear to me what is your goal here. If you just need to intercept all incoming requests why not using some [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for that?

Comment: @AndrewSilver The goal is to forcefully sign them out. And yes, it sounds weird without the context. We have multi-tenant system and a user gaining roles allowing them to access a different tenant has to be forcefully logged out so they will be made to re-sign in. I know when they are coming as "logged in" and when they're coming in as "accepting invite". But I can't react adequately because... well... see question above. I literally need my signed-in user to be forced to authorize regardless (if I detect the invite acceptance from the `returnUrl`.